# How to find godaddy subaccount Id

Tags: godaddy-api

Can anyone please tell me how do I find/get Godaddy subaccount Id.

I have a reseller account and I am working in Godaddy domain register API.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be no API to list all the sub-accounts, but you should be able to find them in the GoDaddy Reseller Control Center - Reports - Customer Lookup.
The `Customer Number` in the report is the shopper ID of each sub-account, you can call this API (https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/shoppers#/v1/get) to retrieve further information.